# Multivariate Time-Series Forecasting in R

Tags: r

I have a data set that consists of a combination of daily and non-daily data that are location specific. The location is specified by the longitude and latitude (columns V1 and V2.) Column V3 represents a location specific value, a heart-disease prevalence indicator. Columns V4 and V5 represent daily location specific recordings for wind speed on days 1-3, 2-4 respectively. Column V6 is daily cases of deaths in the ER for days 1-3; V7 is the deaths for days 2-4; V8 is the deaths for days 3-5.

I would like to create do a multiple linear regression model that can predict the new deaths for the third day in every location, given the values in V1 to V7.
[This is what the data set looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugIWM.png)

This is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,-2,-2,-2,14,14,14,90,90,90,103,103,103,-6,-6,-6,50,50,50,70,70,70,112,112,112,11,11,11,8,8,8,26,26,26,1.2,1.2,1.2,0.8,0.8,0.8,1.3,1.3,1.3,0.7,0.7,0.7,1.7,1.7,1.7,2,2,2,10,20,17,20,25,26,60,70,70,10,12,13,109,117,120,61,67,63,20,17,18,25,26,24,70,70,90,12,13,11,117,120,110,67,63,64,0,4,5,1,4,6,5,7,9,12,23,4,7,6,5,8,9,12,4,5,6,4,6,9,7,9,13,23,4,12,6,5,25,9,12,40,5,6,16 ,6,9,30 ,9,13,32 ,4,12,23 ,5,25,32 ,12,40,61  ), nrow = 18, ncol = 8))

dtrain <- d[1:12,]
dtest <- d[13:18,][1:7]

l <- lm(V8 ~ V1 +V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 + V6 + V7 , data = dtrain)
p <- predict(l,dtest)
```

I would like to know whether having non-daily and daily data mixed together will affect the accuracy of a regression model in such a case. I am new to machine learning and am unsure about the shape of my dataset and how to tackle multivariate regression (in this case a time series,too.)

Comment: At least for this data, it is fine to have daily and non-daily data together as you have done. Also, this doesn't look like a time series.

Comment: I removed the column for the dates, for they are consecutive dates say 2020-01-01, 2020-01-02, 2020-01-03. How else should I trasnform the data?